# Servlet context get real path returns null

Tags: java, jsf

I ma trying to access the resource from src/main/webapp/

I am using java 1.8.0_101 and maven 3.0.3

Unfortunately, it is working in one environment and not in another unix environment

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class TestClass {

    private static final String RESOURCE = "/resources/css/test.css";
    private String css = "";

    public void init(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) ServletContext servletContext) throws IOException {
        String pathString = servletContext.getRealPath(RESOURCE);
        System.out.println("path string: " + pathString);
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(pathString));
        css = new String(data, "UTF-8");
    }

    public String getCss() {
        return css;
    }

    public String format(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof List) {
            List<?> list = (List<?>) o;
            String text = list.toString();
            return text.substring(1, text.length() - 1);
        }
        return o == null ? "" : o.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

please check with this

```
ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
String relativeWebPath = "img/image.png";
String absoluteDiskPath = servletContext.getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
```